# use query_string and range in elasticsearch php client [query_string] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: php, elasticsearch, range, query-string, elasticsearch-dsl

i use below code and get below error
for connect php to elasticsearch i use elasticsearch php client

```
    $params = [
    'index'=>'index1,index2',
    'from'=>$startfrom,
    'size'=>$maxperpage,
    'sort'  => array('id:desc'),
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'query_string' => [
                'query' => "\"$search_text\""
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

if($limit_time['start']){
    $params['body']['query']['range']['date_insert']['gte']=$limit_time['start'];
}
if($limit_time['end']){
    $params['body']['query']['range']['date_insert']['lte']=$limit_time['end'];
}
```

error :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[query_string] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":104}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[query_string] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":104},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved problem
but thanks a lot "Val" for your help

i use below code :

```
    $params = [
    'index'=>'index1,index2',
    'from'=>$startfrom,
    'size'=>$maxperpage,
    'sort'  => array('id:desc')
];

if($search_text){
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][0]['match_phrase']['src']=$search_text;
}

if($use_time_status){
    if($limit_time['start']){
        $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][1]['range']['date_insert']['gte']=$limit_time['start'];
    }
    if($limit_time['end']){
        $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][1]['range']['date_insert']['lte']=$limit_time['end'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this instead. The `query_string` and the `range` queries need to be combined into a `bool/filter` query:

```
$params = [
    'index'=>'index1,index2',
    'from'=>$startfrom,
    'size'=>$maxperpage,
    'sort'  => array('id:desc'),
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'filter' => [
                    [
                        'query_string' => [
                            'query' => "\"$search_text\""
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

$range = ['range' => ['date_insert' => []]]
if($limit_time['start']){
    $range['range']['date_insert']['gte'] = $limit_time['start'];
}
if($limit_time['end']){
    $range['range']['date_insert']['lte'] = $limit_time['end'];
}

$params['body']['query']['bool']['filter'][] = $range;
```

Comment: thank you Val for your answer, but this code not work and i get below error :

Comment: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"unknown query [date_insert]","line":1,"col":139}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:139] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]","caused_by":{"type":"parsing_exception","reason"

Comment: :"unknown query [date_insert]","line":1,"col":139,"caused_by":{"type":"named_object_not_found_exception","reason":"[1:139] unknown field [date_insert]"}}},"status":400}